# Pages attribute does not appear in the bibliography

Tags: citing

I am trying to cite from books and articles but I have recently  noticed that the page attribute does not appear in the bibliography. Otherwise, everything else appear in the bibliography.

How can I fix it?

**main tex file**

```
    \documentclass[
        english,
        german,
        11pt,
        twoside,
        a4paper,
        BCOR8.25mm,
        DIV10,
        headsepline,
        footsepline
    ]{scrbook}
    \include{commands}

    \begin{document}

    \selectlanguage{english}
    \frontmatter

    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Frontpage
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \input{0-titlepage.tex}

    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % contents
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \tableofcontents
        \cleardoublepage

    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % The normal content
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \mainmatter
        \pagestyle{fancy}

        \include{1-introduction}    

        \include{6-conclusion}


            %---------------------------------------------------------------------------

            \printnomenclature

            \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
            \bibliography{bibliography}

    \printindex


\end{document}
```

**bibliography.bib**

```
@artikel{EasyTracker,
  author = {Tomas Gerlich, James Biagioni, Jakob Eriksson},
  title = {EasyTracker: Automatic Transit Tracking, Mapping, and Arrival Time Prediction Using Smartphones},
  year = {2010},
  pages = {2}
}

@book{facca2010,
    author    = "Daniel, Florian, Facca, Federico Michele",
    title     = "Current Trends in Web Engineering, ICWE 2010 Workshops",
    year      = "2010",
    pages      = "245"

}

@comment{BibDesk Smart Groups{
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>conditions</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>comparison</key>
                <integer>2</integer>
                <key>key</key>
                <string>Keywords</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>java</string>
                <key>version</key>
                <string>1</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>comparison</key>
                <integer>2</integer>
                <key>key</key>
                <string>Keywords</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>spec</string>
                <key>version</key>
                <string>1</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>conjunction</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>group name</key>
        <string>Java Specifications</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>conditions</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>comparison</key>
                <integer>2</integer>
                <key>key</key>
                <string>Keywords</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>osgi</string>
                <key>version</key>
                <string>1</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>conjunction</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>group name</key>
        <string>OSGi</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
}}
```

Comment: There is no `@artikel` type defined in the bib style; the lists of authors are wrong: authors should be separated from one another with the keyword `and`. For instance, `author = {Tomas Gerlich and James Biagioni and Jakob Eriksson}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run BibTeX, you get the following warning:

```
Warning--entry type for "EasyTracker" isn't style-file defined
--line 1 of file bibliography.bib
```

The `artikel` type indeed does not exist; it *must* be `article`.

Note also that the lists of authors are wrong: authors should be separated from each other by the keyword `and`.

```
@article{EasyTracker,
  author = {Tomas Gerlich and James Biagioni and Jakob Eriksson},
  title = {EasyTracker: Automatic Transit Tracking, Mapping, and Arrival Time Prediction Using Smartphones},
  year = {2010},
  pages = {2}
}

@book{facca2010,
    author    = "Daniel, Florian and Facca, Federico Michele",
    title     = "Current Trends in Web Engineering, ICWE 2010 Workshops",
    year      = "2010",
    pages      = "245"

}
```

Note also that a `publisher` field is missing in the second entry and a `journal` field in the first one.

[image]

Comment: Ok it appears now for article but it does not appear for book?!

Comment: @MrAsker - Did you remember to replace the comma between "Florian" and "Facca" with `and` -- a keyword?

Comment: @egreg: Sorry again I have replaced it but the page does not appear in Bibliography `. In your Bibliography I am not seeing the page `245`!

Comment: For me your answer works for articel but not for book but I will marked it as answered.

Comment: @MrAsker The `book` type ignores the `pages` field, at least in the `ieeetr.bst` style.

Comment: @egreg: Please last question; which `\bibliographystyle` can I use to oder the cite number  successive and to show the `@book` pages?

Comment: @MrAsker Usually the number of pages in a book is not relevant for a citation. In the bibliography entry for an article one specifies the page range in the journal issue, not the page where something we want to point to appears.

Comment: @MrAsker Note that the BibTeX citations obtained through Google Scholar for the two publications you show are rather poor.